# Find specific matching values of two columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have spreadsheet like the following. In that columns detection_BaP1 and detection_NT1 are having Absent and Present. I want to add a new column Global_detection with Absent and Present

If both detection_BaP1 and detection_NT1 are "Absent" give "Absent" in Global_detection, else give "Present"

```
tracking_id coverage_BaP1   coverage_NT1    BaP1    NT1 FC        detection_BaP1    detection_NT1   Global_detection
NM_000028   1.06E-14    1.35E-44    1.65E-15    2.40E-45    6.87E+29   Absent   Absent  
NM_000041   1.50439 0.472338    0.26732 0.0828073   3.228217802 Present Absent  
NM_000055   0.0677437   0.135153    0.0103961   0.0236942   -2.27914314 Absent  Absent  
NM_000061   0.0315361   0.0939712   0.00967921  0.033096    -3.419287318    Absent  Absent  
NM_000067   112.34  204.529 17.5228 36.5017 -2.08309745 Present Present 
NM_000070   0.00346421  0.0089972   0.000629599 0.00174727  -2.775210888    Absent  Absent  
NM_000072   4.78E-08    2.81E-07    8.52E-09    6.28E-08    -7.368209171    Absent  Absent  
NM_000076   0.901573    0.452928    0.141912    0.0806631   1.759317457 Absent  Absent  
NM_000084   2.40985 0.252053    0.378136    0.0454107   8.327024248 Present Absent  
NM_000087   1.2429  1.7001  0.216543    0.360131    -1.663092319    Present Present
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use `IF()` and `AND()`:

`=IF(AND(A2="Absent",B2="Absent"),"Absent","Present")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But when I did that I got this #NOM?

Comment: "But when I did that" - what exactly you did? Please add a screenshot of your actual data and also what you've tried to your question. `#NOM` doesn't seem to be in english, in which language do you use excel? probably you need to translate function to the language of excel too.